# Book series I read a few years back with a Marine doing a combat jump onto a planet

Tags: story-identification, books

In the first book the main character joined the Marines and is making his first combat jump onto a planet. No fighting between the main factions happens in our solar system or Alpha Centauri due to the fact that the Earth was almost destroyed. Humans have colonies on planets throughout the galaxy, and are able to get to them by going through hyperspace lanes. There are two European factions with one of them being called the European Confederation or something similar, a North American faction, a South American Faction, and a Russian Indochina faction.

In a later book we are introduced to the North American's spy agency where (potential spoiler) Number Three is the Marine Commander.

Comment: Reminiscent of [Starship Troopers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starship_Troopers) but a lot of that is set on Earth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you thinking of the *Crimson Worlds* series? Book 1, [*Marines*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/16050877-marines) starts with a combat drop.

> Erik Cain joined the marines to get off death row. The deal was simple; enlist to fight in space and he would be pardoned for all his crimes.
>
> In the 23rd Century, assault troops go to war wearing AI-assisted, nuclear-powered armor, but it is still men and blood that win battles. From one brutal campaign to the next, Erik and his comrades fight an increasingly desperate war over the resource rich colony worlds that have become vital to the economies of Earth's exhausted and despotic Superpowers.
>
> As Erik rises through the ranks he finally finds a home, first with the marines who fight at his side and later among the colonists - men and women who have dared to leave everything behind to build a new society on the frontier, one where the freedoms and rights lost long ago on Earth are preserved.
>
> Amidst the blood and death and sacrifice, Erik begins to wonder. Is he fighting the right war? Who is the real enemy?

Comment: Hi there! Could you [edit] in elements that match what the asker describes? A summary (yours or someone else's) for instance, or icing on the cake, quotes if you have some. This would make for a better answer :)